# Converting Parse Tree Into AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) C++

Tags: c++, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, parse-tree

I have a parse tree that parses out a stack of a stack of char `(stack<stack<char>>)`. This gets the characters into a parse tree. My question is how would I convert this parse tree into a AST in order to evaluate it?

I have the evaluator working for a AST I just need to convert the tree into the syntax in order to evaluate it.

Any help would be appreciated.

[Here is a picture of what I am trying to accomplish](http://dfwebdesign.net/example.png)

Comment: I don't see a tree in a stack of stacks of chars

Comment: If the string was originally 

`5+6 - (4*6) + 5` the stack of stack of chars would be
`[[5] [+] [6] [-] [(] [4] [*] [6] [)] [+] [5]]`

That is turned into a parse tree

Comment: How is this stack of stacks different from any plain old stack? Do any inner stack have more than one item, ever? Also, where's the stack? I see a sequence of characters that repeats the input sequence verbatim. What is the transformation here?

Comment: The stack of characters is not what is important, the important thing is that I have a tree that has the characters in it as well as nodes for the + minus parenthesis and so on. I need to convert that tree into a ast so it will have a full node. [Here is a picture of what I am trying to accomplish](http://dfwebdesign.net/example.png), I will edit the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to convert them using a [Tree Traversal Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

Using Pre Order Traversal

```
preorder(node)
  if node == null then return
  print node.value
  preorder(node.left) 
  preorder(node.right)
```

Using a stack to store the leaf nodes I added the values onto them and was able to transverse the stack and change into lea nodes.

A example for 10 + 4

the parse tree leafs using preorder would give me a stack of [+ 10 4]

Using a helper function I could convert this into a

Make_Plus(Make_Int(10), Make_Int(4)) by using recursion